# One size fits all

Tags: cryptic-clues

Reconstructing a lab before a sea next to seething hot substance is required when travelling extremely fast.

> 9 letters

What am I ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a

> BALACLAVA (worn for warmth/protection when travelling fast - BALA for anagram of "a lab", C for "sea", and LAVA for "seething hot substance")